# I need to validate and send feedback to a participating server. How can we add Netty request code channel.write() within handler code?

Tags: multithreading, netty

1. I am coding for a Netty based Notifying Server, which takes in Message Buffer many hundreds at a second from a Server(A) through RPC, and then sends it to an Http Real Time Server, after checking for the validity(the validation consists of checking for a tag ID and its value). If the validation is not successful, the System needs to send an error feedback back to the Server(A) with an Error Code.
   I intend to write the validation logic inside a handler, but how do we make the handler to send the feedback if message is found to be invalid?
2. Can we include database code also into a handler, so I can persist the validation specific details to a Database? Will adding this DB code handicap the Netty performance? If Yes, what's the better way of using a Database (insert) code inside a handler?
   Please can anyone guide me? Can I write the DB code inside an Executor?

Kindly excuse me if I am asking a too basic questions. I am still on Learning phase.

Comment: It is ok to ask basic questions. It is not ok to ask question*s* (multiple in one body).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to answer the questions.

1) I think it does not not matter if you want to send an ERROR or SUCCESS response. Just use Channel.write(..) to write it and have an encoder that can handle the encoding to a ChannelBuffer. There is not difference here

2) You should add an ExecutionHandler in front to make sure your db calls do not block the IO-Thread. See [1].

[1] http://netty.io/docs/stable/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/execution/ExecutionHandler.html